# GpuMat::upload stalls when called in thread?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, pthreads

Below is a simple program where it seems that my thread stalls when I try to upload an image to the GPU, where upload() does not return. The device info calls all work fine, and return appropriate values.

1. Is uploading to the GPU possible in a thread?
2. If so, what am I doing wrong below and how can I make it work?

Here is my simple test code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp" // For GPU processing

using namespace std;


void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
    cv::gpu::GpuMat gInputImage, gOutputImage;
    cv::Mat image, image2, image3;

    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadid;

    cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << tid << endl;
    cout << "loading image in main memory" << endl;
    image = cv::imread("tdf_1972_poster.jpg");

    cout << "deviceID: " << cv::gpu::getDevice() << endl;
    cv::gpu::DeviceInfo mydeviceinfo = cv::gpu::DeviceInfo();
    cout << "name: " << mydeviceinfo.name() << endl;

    cv::gpu::setDevice(0); // I don't think this will help at all.

    cout << "cols before cpu resize: " << image.cols << endl;
    cv::resize(image, image2, cv::Size(), .5, 0.5, cv::INTER_NEAREST);
    cout << "cols after cpu resize: " << image2.cols << endl;

    cout << "cols before gpu resize: " << image.cols << endl;
    gInputImage.upload(image); // thread stalls here.
    cv::gpu::resize(gInputImage, gOutputImage, cv::Size(), .5, 0.5, cv::INTER_NEAREST);
    gOutputImage.download(image3);
    cout << "cols after gpu resize: " << image3.cols << endl;

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
    pthread_t threads[1];
    int rc;
    int i;

    cout << "main() : creating thread, "<< endl;
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, PrintHello, 0);
    if (rc){
      cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
main() : creating thread, 
Hello World! Thread ID, 0
loading image in main memory
deviceID: 0
name: GeForce GTX 560 Ti
cols before cpu resize: 374
cols after cpu resize: 187
cols before gpu resize: 374
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was not patient enough. I forgot how long it takes for that first GPU call to return due to the on-the-fly compilation.